# Writing a program that, if given an array of characters, will output array that has the indices in order from largest to smallest (java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I'm working through a problem that if I have an array of characters it wants me to arrange them in order from largest to smallest but by the index not the actual letter. so ex, `a[] = { 'a', 'z', 'p'}` the output array would be like `b[] = {1 , 2, 0}

I understand how to sort the array of characters into descending order but now I'm confused on how to relate the two arrays together. I'm thinking I need to copy the original array into another array and then compare them someway. But im confused on the steps i need to take to get there. My sorting code is below just for reference. if anyone can help me out that would be great. Thanks

```
public static void main(String[]args){

       char[] a ={'f','a','z','v','t','u','i','j','o','c'};
       int[] b ;
     
     
     
       // Sort a
       for(int i= 0; i <= a.length-2;i++){
           
           int maxindex = i;
           
           for(int j = maxindex+1; j<a.length; j++){
               if(a[j]>a[maxindex]){
                   maxindex = j;
               }
           }
           // swap
           char temp = a[i];
           a[i] = a[maxindex];
           a[maxindex] = temp;
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
           System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi! It was a bit more challenging than I thought. Here is what I did:

1. Make a copy from the original array.
2. Sort the original array.
3. Compare the two arrays so you can get the array with indexes

It's just like you thought. I think you could simplify the code using other types of structures, but it's fine if it is to practice java

```
char[] sorted = {'z','f','z','v','t','u','i','j','o','k','b'}; 

// Let's copy it
char[] copy = sorted.clone();

// initialize b as an array of integer with the same size as 'sorted' array
int[] b= new int[sorted.length];

 // Sort your original array (this is your code)
for(int i= 0; i <= sorted.length-2;i++){
    
    int maxindex = i;
    
    for(int j = maxindex+1; j<sorted.length; j++){
        if(sorted[j]>sorted[maxindex]){
            maxindex = j;
        }
    }
    // swap
    char temp = sorted[i];
    sorted[i] = sorted[maxindex];
    sorted[maxindex] = temp;
}

// let's see what we got
for(int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
    System.out.print(sorted[i] + " ");
}

// now let's compare the original vs the sorted and get the indexes array
for(int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < copy.length; k++){
        if ((copy[k] == sorted[i] && i == 0)  || (copy[k] == sorted[i] && k != b[i - 1]) ) {
               b[i] = k; 
               break;
           }                  
    }
}


System.out.print("\n");

// let's see the indexes array
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: okay so my train of thought was definitely going in the right direction. for the final for loop to compare the sorted and copied arrays do you need to put the whole if statement? Wouldnt it just work if you just had if ( copy[k] == sorted[i] )?

Comment: Yes you can, but you wouldn't be getting a "right" result when there are repeated characters in the original array. Example: for array = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'c'] you will get [1, 1, 2, 0] instead of [1, 3, 2, 0]

Comment: Anytime. Don't forget to mark the question as answered